# Error in Ubuntu Unattended Installation - Failed to mount Fuse control file system, Kernel configuration file system

Tags: 18.04, pxe, tftp

I am performing netboot unattended installation using a local server. But during the installation, I received the below error:

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgtXe.png)

Note: I am installing Ubuntu-18.04 (bionic) Desktop version.

Please comment if more information is required.